# cant_delete_file even if I have the right scopes?

Tags: slack-api, slack

Since Slack doesn't support bulk delete, I have searched for alternatives. The search didn't took long, and I stumbled upon [this Python script](http://www.shiftedup.com/2014/11/13/how-to-bulk-remove-files-from-slack) which use Slack's Web API to delete all files that are there for more than 30 days.

After struggling to get the token right, I got a valid token with the scopes `files:read` and `files:write:user`.

The script starts, gets the list of files, and sends the request to delete correctly, but the answer from Slack is systematic:

```
{"ok":false,"error":"cant_delete_file"}
```

Searching for this error code reveals it is because I don't have the permissions to do erase them.

I can't find any more information, and I'm struggling to know what goes wrong. What is the reason I don't have the permissions?

Comment: This can be because you try to delete a file uploaded by another user without being an admin. Are you an admin?

Comment: @FrançoisF: Revisiting my old question to accept answer, I indeed misconfigured the script and used the wrong token. Refreshing the token with admin permission solved the problem and I am using it since then. Could you repost your comment as a answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to be authenticated as an **admin user** to delete a file that belongs to another user.

I would agree that the error message could give more details about the situation.

**Edit: this answer is outdated, see [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39665477/cant-delete-file-even-if-i-have-the-right-scopes/43136905#comment116065844_43136905).**

Comment: Can a bot delete files if it has admin permissions?

Comment: @avi I am not familiar with bots, but perhaps you can tell us in a few minutes? =)

Comment: @DrakaSAN I have the same issue. I added app to workspace with `files:read` and `files:write:user`, then Log In with Slack as a user with the same scopes, LIST files works well, but delete not. My user is not an admin user. It does mean, that I can not delete my own files via API?

Comment: What do you mean by authenticated as an admin user? I'm the workspace owner (and admin). I've installed the app myself, but it still doesn't have permission to delete files.

Comment: @Josh I no longer have a Slack instance I can test, so the best I can do is provide a link to the API docs: https://api.slack.com/methods/files.delete

Comment: Thanks, I followed that page as best as I could figure out but I still got the error, even after enabling maximum permissions.

Comment: The Slack permissions system has changed, and it looks like it is no longer possible to access the API with user tokens. Instead, you are prompted to create an app, grant it permissions, and use the app's token. Problem is, apps can't be admin users.